# Goldman ideal as an isolated prime through a special ring map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to find some connections between the following two definitions. Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $\mathfrak p\subset A$ be a prime ideal.

1. $\mathfrak p$ is a *Goldman ideal* if there is some $f\in A$ such that $V (\mathfrak p)\cap D(f) =\{\mathfrak p\}$, i.e., the only prime in $D(f)$ containing $\mathfrak p$ is $\mathfrak p$.
2. Let $\phi: B\to A$ be a finite type ring map. Then $\mathfrak p$ is a *isolated prime through $\phi$* if there is some $f\in A$ so that the only prime $\mathfrak q$ in $D(f)\subset \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ with $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak q) = \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ is $\mathfrak q = \mathfrak p$.

Given a Goldman ideal $\mathfrak p\subset A$, I am guessing it should be a isolated prime through some finite type ring map $\phi$(Strangely we are constructing a map left to the ring $A$.) The map should satisfy $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak q) = \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ iff $\mathfrak q\subset\mathfrak p$. How should we construct the map?

As a reference since the definition for isolated prime is usually different from 2., see equivalent condition (3) [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00PK) on Stacks Project.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense - I think you're misunderstanding the meaning of isolated point in a fiber. For any ring $R$ and the identity map $R \to R$, every prime is an isolated point in its fiber, and this obviously has nothing to do with being Goldman

Comment: @math54321 To state the question again using the fiber, fix a ring $A$ and a prime $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. I am looking for a finite type morphism $\phi^* : \operatorname{Spec}(A)\to\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ such that the fiber at $\phi^*(\mathfrak p)$ is $V(\mathfrak p)$, i.e., ${\phi^*}^{-1}(\phi^* (\mathfrak p)) = V(\mathfrak p) \subset \operatorname{Spec}(A).$

Comment: Well this new condition in your comment has nothing to do with being an isolated point in a fiber (and presumably you want to assume Goldman there). So you should either edit your question to state what you actually want, without introducing unrelated terms, or make a new question entirely